# Mock factory using jest in typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, winston

I want to create a mocked [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) logger instance using Jest.

This is so that I can use dependency injection to spy on how many times `logger.warning()` has been called and with what error message.

However because winston uses a factory method `createLogger()`, when doing an auto mock on `jest.mock("winston")` it will make my calls to `createLogger()` return undefined.

Here is my code:

```js
import { VoiceChannelDisconnect } from "./../../src/PeriodicTask/VoiceChannelDisconnect";
import { Logger, createLogger } from "winston";
import { VoiceChannel, GuildMember, Collection } from "discord.js";
jest.mock("winston");
jest.mock("discord.js");

const MockedVoiceChannel = VoiceChannel as jest.Mock<VoiceChannel>;
let voiceChannel = new MockedVoiceChannel();
let logger = createLogger();
let voiceChannelDisconnect = new VoiceChannelDisconnect(voiceChannel, logger);

it("returns true when no one is left in channel", () => {
  voiceChannel = new MockedVoiceChannel();
  voiceChannel.members = new Collection<string, GuildMember>();

  logger = createLogger();
  logger.warning = jest.fn();

  voiceChannelDisconnect = new VoiceChannelDisconnect(voiceChannel, logger);
  expect(voiceChannelDisconnect.execute()).toBe(true);
  expect(logger.warning).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Running the test yields:

```
    TypeError: Cannot set property 'warning' of undefined

      15 | 
      16 |   logger = createLogger();
    > 17 |   logger.warning = jest.fn();
```

How do I create a mock `Logger` instance that still satisfies Typescript's type checks?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this issue by modifying the issue presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771616/how-to-use-jest-to-mock-winston-logger-instance-encapsulated-in-service-class)

By putting this:

```
jest.mock("winston", () => ({
  createLogger: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    debug: jest.fn(),
    warning: jest.fn()
  })
}));
```

At the top of the test, `createLogger`, I can now track how many times `logger.warning` has been called